# DbSet.ToList() seeds other dbset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using entity framework in my application, and I have a one-to-many models like this:

```
public class Email
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AnexoEmail> Anexos{get;set;}
}

public class AnexoEmail
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Full path do ficheiro
    /// </summary>
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataEnvio { get; set; }
    public bool Enviado { get; set; }

    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }
}
```

It represents like a Email-Attachment relation. The thing is that I have a `UOW` and repository `EmailRepository` and something that I can't understand happens:
On the repository:

```
public class EmailRepository : IEmailRepository
{
    internal DbContext _context;
    internal DbSet<Email> dbSet;
    internal DbSet<AnexoEmail> dbSetAnexo;

    public EmailRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<Email>();
        dbSetAnexo = context.Set<AnexoEmail>();
    }
    (...)
    public IEnumerable<Email> GetAll()
    {
        dbSetAnexo.ToList(); //<- I can´t understand this part

        var emails = dbSet.ToList();
        return email;
    }
}
```

In this example I'm expecting `emails.Anexos` to be `null`, but for some reason, if I add that line the `emails.Anexos` gets the correct attachments(anexos), and if I don't `emails.Anexos` will be null as expected.

I don't have much experience in Ef core, if I'm missing some class or anything just tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: EF will track entities, so if you do `dbSetAnexo.AsNoTracking().ToList();` I bet it stops working.

Comment: But why does it seed the collecion `emails.Anexo` if I'm not using the return value of `dbSetAnexo.ToList();`? @DavidG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all caused by [entity tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking). The line `dbSetAnexo.ToList();` causes Entity Framework to *track* the entire `DbSet`, you can think of it as a form of caching if you like. Because EF has "cached" those `AnexoEmail` objects, it will present them to you when you request the value of `email.Anexos`.

You can prevent this from happening by using the [`AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-2.1) extension method, for example:

```
dbSetAnexo.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Now, what you should be doing instead is using the `Include` function which will force EF to [load up the specified related children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). For example:

```
var emails = dbSet
    .Include(e => e.Anexos)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: So, with the `Include` I can seed the "child" model? That makes sense and is something that I was missing on my project. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `Include` tells EF to load child entities. If you had children of children, you could also use `ThenInclude`, for example: `dbSet.Include(e => e.Anexos).ThenInclude(a => a.Whatever)`

Comment: @DavidG beat me to it! To compliment his answer what you are seeing is the differences between Lazy Loading and Eager Loading. Include() eagerly loads specified child entities. If left out, EF generates proxy queries that are deferred to the last possible moment. Basically EF won't execute the queries for child entities until you tell EF you want the child entity. Here is [MSDN's Explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) of the topic.

Comment: @bman7716 I didn't specifically mention lazy loading that's only in version 2.1 which isn't available yet (it went to release candidate yesterday!)

Comment: @bman7716 Actually the explanation of the OP described behavior is contained in the second **Tip** in your link - *"Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded."*

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right and thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with what `.ToList()` actually does. It doesn't change the original value of the collection, it just creates a new `List<>` and returns it. What you're currently doing is throwing the value out the window, and not doing anything with it. There are two ways to store it:

```
DbSet<AnexoEmail> dbSetAnexo;     // Keep original DbSet<>
List<AnexoEmail> listAnexo;       // Make new List<AnexoEmail>

listAnexo = dbSetAnexo.ToList();
```

Then, you would use `listAnexo` instead of `dbSetAnexo`. If you don't like that, and want to use only one variable, you can use the `dynamic` type which is the only type that can change from one type to another during runtime.

```
dynamic anexoEmails = new DbSet<AnexoEmail>();    // anexoEmails is currently a dBSet<>
anexoEmails = anexoEmails.ToList();               // anexoEmails is now a List<>
```

The latter might behavior more like you expected it would. Just keep in mind, with `dynamic` types, you're not gonna get as much compiler checking, and no IDE autocompletetion as all of that is check during runtime.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question (it is a little vague)

Comment: Yes, the questions is a little vague. I know I'm throwing the value "out of the window" and that is what I don't understand. Why does `emails.Anexo` have a collection with the correct values with that line (doing nothing to my knowledge), and if I delete it (the line) `emails.Anexo` is `null` as expected.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The question is 'In this example I'm expecting emails.Anexos to be null, but for some reason, if I add that line the emails.Anexos gets the correct attachments(anexos), and if I don't emails.Anexos will be null as expected.' This answer doesn't explain why EF linked the Anexos (`dbSetAnexos.ToList()`) records back to the second query for Emails (`dbSet.ToList()`)